# Increment the numeric part of a string identifier in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell, increment, identifier

I have this code (I'm a Haskell newbie).

```
import Data.List.Split

padL :: Int -> String -> String
padL n s
    | length s < n = replicate (n - length s) '0' ++ s
    | otherwise = s

strInc :: String -> String -> String
strInc sep str = 
        let strarr = splitOn sep str
            zprefix = strarr !! 0
            znumber = strarr !! 1
        in zprefix ++ sep ++ padL ( length (znumber) ) ( show ( read ( znumber ) + 1 ) )
```

Is it bad, average or good Haskell code? How can it be improved?
Thanks.

Comment: I think Stackoverflow is not the right place to ask this. The site is about questions, not code reviews. For code reviews, there is http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I'm asking about idiomatic Haskell I may not be aware of. There is already an accepted and answered "How should I refactor this Haskell..." question, similar to mine. I could reformulate without my code if it helps, the title is self explanatory about what my question is.

Comment: If at all possible, maintain the numeric part of the identifier separately and only add the string part later. Having an numeric increment function of type `String -> String` seems unpleasant. If you could wrap your number in a `newtype` with a custom read and show to achieve your end result, that would be nicer. (Not sure what you're using this for, which is why I'm uncertain.)

Comment: This is a learning exercise. It's part of a "how do you do this in that language". I proposed the above code in Haskell, but I wanted to conduct a scrutiny for my own personal Haskell development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import Data.List.Split
```

Not being afraid of using non-base packages:  This is good.

```
-- Original code
padL :: Int -> String -> String
padL n s
    | length s < n = replicate (n - length s) '0' ++ s
    | otherwise = s
```

Unneeded cases: this is not "bad" but "silly".  Consider instead:

```
-- New code
padL n s = replicate (n - length s) '0' ++ s
```

If `length s >= n` then `replicate (0 or negative) '0' == ""` and this answer is the same as your otherwise case.

```
-- Original code
strInc :: String -> String -> String
strInc sep str = 
        let strarr = splitOn sep str
            zprefix = strarr !! 0
            znumber = strarr !! 1
        in zprefix ++ sep ++ padL ( length (znumber) ) ( show ( read ( znumber ) + 1 ) )
```

Using indexing into lists (!!): this is bad because it is ugly and can fail (what if the list is shorter than you expected?).

Over-use of parens: This is annoying

How about:

```
-- New code
strInc :: String -> String -> String
strInc sep str =
    case splitOn sep str of
      (zprefix:znumber:_) -> zprefix ++ sep ++ padL (length znumber) (show (read znumber + 1))
      _ -> "" -- some error value
```

Over all very good work.  Nicely done.

Comment: So replicate works with negative values. Nice one.
I'm really taken with your strInc function! One thing I have to ask, why the _ as the tail in the first test case for the case?
And thank you!

Comment: Ahh, so the `_` is just notation for an unamed variable in a pattern match, `zprefix:znumber:restOfList == zprefix:znumber:_`  Notice this is slightly different than `[zprefix,znumber]`, which will only match on a list of two elements (instead of two OR MORE elements).

Comment: I see, if I use more than one separator, it will only manage the second element, and loose the tail. By the way, how do I handle the case where znumber doesn't convert to a number, i.e. znumber = 00001a? Thanks.

Comment: You can use readMaybe and pattern match or use the `maybe` function.